# How can I split a string based on chaging characters rather than one single separator?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm looking for a solution in java that will allow me to split a String like this one "MM/dd/yyyy", not based on the "/" slash but based on the change from "M" to "d" and from "d" to "y"?

The reason is that I may also need to split a string using this logic that has no separator at all, for example "yyMMdd". Note: I'm looking for splitting the pattern string itself, and not some actual date string which follows those patterns.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do that, rather than converting the string to `Date` object, and getting the 3 components from it?

Comment: Trust me I have my reasons. The SimpleDateFormat conversion will not work 100% for me.

Comment: There is no easy way to get this done, if the format is not fixed, and you're not sure about what delimiter is coming, or whether it is coming or not. Regex is not good at identifying the semantics of a text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you just want to split pattern - `yy/MM/dd` or any other, and not an actual date formatted to those patterns, I would rather use `Matcher` here, instead of `split()`.

```
String patternString = "yy/MM/dd";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("y+|M+|d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(patternString);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

This solution rather than splitting on some unknown delimiter, just finds a sequence of `y` or `M` or `d` (As in any pattern, those will be coming in sequence only).

Answer (score 0):

If you always know the format, such as `yyMMdd` you can just split on every character and assume each 2 characters are the ones that you want. To do this you'd use split without a delimiter: `split('')`

Comment: That's a terrible idea though.

Comment: It get's the job done and it is a hell of a lot easier than looking at regular expressions for what I assume is the first time

Comment: For one thing -> The format is not fixed, else I would definitely use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: I don't know the format. The format may be one of the many possible formats. That's why I'm looking for some logic that will allow me to detect the change from one char to another and split on that.

Comment: @goe Problem is, you're not detecting change from 1 char to another, but from 1 digit to another. And since same digit can come in both `yy`, `MM` and `dd` part, it would be impossible to do this with `split()`.

Comment: @RohitJain We are not talking about actual dates here ie "01/05/2015". I want to split the incoming date format (ie. pattern) into pieces.

Comment: What you want is impossible there is no way for a computer to just know when the day / month / year changes unless you tell it where it's changing

Comment: @goe Oh!! Well, that can be easily done. Lemme post an answer.